# Hiding a column based on a parameter using an expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have been trying to hide a column in a 2017 SSRS Report and have tried several examples that I have found here on the site but getting errors with all of them.

Here is the expression I'm trying to fix:

```
=iif(Parameters!School.Label Like "*Middle*",False,True)
```

I have also tried Contains with the same error.

When clicking on Preview and selecting my parameters I get the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The Hidden expression for the tablix `Tablix1` contains an error: Operateor 'Like' is not defined for type 'String()' and String "*Middle*".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should handle the NULL values so the following expresion will help you;

```
=IIF((IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!School.Label),"NULLValue",Parameters!School.Label)).Contains("Middle"),"False","True")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your School parameter default value NULL? That might be a reason why it fails to evaluate. If it is, try setting some other default value for testing.

Comment: Tried the option that esat offered and still get the same error when generating the report.   The Hidden expression for the tablix 'Tablix1' contains an error: Public member 'Contains'on type'String()' not found. This error comes up AFTER I select all the parameters and click View Report

Comment: Also tried adding a default value to the school parameter and still have the same error

Comment: @Wayne Is it a multivalue parameter? Maybe try making a dummy report with the same dataset and parameters and a test tablix. Try to replicate the problem there. I am unable to get that error message.

Comment: I tried with a  new report and even though a user can select multiple schools from the parameter I've tested using just one school both containing Middle and without and still get the same error.

Comment: @Wayne I think the problem is with the multivalue parameter. You are treating it as a string while it might contain a list of strings. Try joining label values before using Like or Contains.